# image 404 (Not Found) after uploading, but working when re-compiling webpack

Tags: angular, mean-stack, image-upload

I'm creating a **MEAN STACK CRUD** App(with Angular CLI). **Problem :** when i am uploading a picture, it not show on the page with having a **ERROR :** `GET http://localhost:4200/assets/images/uploadedProfilePic5ac9ade58bd8213eecf2aa50.jpg 404 (Not Found)`.
But it **immediately shows up when angular re-compiling webpack**. there is no issue with the image upload process. it working fine. images are uploaded where it should be upload(`src/assets/images`), no issue with that also.
what should i do now?.

**My Service that upload pics :**

```
//upload Picture service
  uploadProfilePic(id, file)
  {
    const req = new HttpRequest(
      'POST', 
      'http://localhost:3000/users/uploadPic/'+id, file, {
      reportProgress: true
    });

    return this.http.request(req).map(res => {return res});
  }
```

My **upload-profile-pic.component.ts** File :

```
onUpload(e)  
  {
    // console.log(e);

    const uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append("uploadedProfilePic", this.file);

    this.auth.uploadProfilePic(this.id, uploadData).subscribe((data:any) => {

      if(data.type == 1){
        // console.log(Math.round(data.loaded*100/data.total));
        this.progressBarValue = Math.round(data.loaded*100/data.total);
      }

    setTimeout(()=>{ 
      if(data.type == 4){
        // console.log(data);
      var updateData = {avatar: "uploadedProfilePic"+this.id+'.'+this.ext};

      if(data.body.success) {
        this.auth.updateUserService(this.id, updateData).subscribe((data:any)=> {
          // console.log(data);
          if(data.success){
            this.flashMsg.show("Success: "+ data.msg, {cssClass: 'flashMessageBox', timeout: 6000});
            this.router.navigate(['/userList']);
          }else{
            this.flashMsg.show("Error: "+ data.msg, {cssClass: 'flashMessageBox', timeout: 6000});
            // this.reset();
            this.router.navigate(['/userList']);
          }
        });

      }else {
        this.flashMsg.show("Error: "+ data.body.msg, {cssClass: 'flashMessageBox', timeout: 6000});
        // this.reset();
        this.router.navigate(['/userList']);
        }
      }
    }, 2000);

    });


  }
```

My **user list html file** where shows the image :

```
<div *ngFor = "let user of usersList">
    <div class="row mb-2 mx-auto" id="showUserList">

      <div class="col-sm-2 p-0 text-center">

        <img *ngIf="!user.avatar == ''" src="{{photoBaseUrl}}/{{user.avatar}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="user image" id="profilePic1">
        <img *ngIf="user.avatar == ''" src="{{photoBaseUrl}}/usergroup.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="user image" id="profilePic2">
        <div class="overlay">
          <p class="addPicText" routerLink="/uploadProfilePic/{{user._id}}">
            <i class="far fa-user addPhIcon"></i>
            <br> 
            Update
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="card-body py-0">
          <h5 class="card-title text-capitalize my-0 pt-1">{{user.name}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text text-muted p-0 m-0 font-sm">Email : {{user.email}}</p>
          <p class="card-text text-muted p-0 m-0 font-sm">Phone : {{user.phone}}</p>
          <p class="card-text text-muted p-0 m-0 text-capitalize font-sm">Active : {{user.active}}</p>         
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3 pr-0 mr-0">
        <div class="w-75 mx-auto mt-2 text-uppercase">
          <p 
            routerLink="/editUser/{{user._id}}" 
            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block btnStyleSuccess font-xs m-0 p-1 mb-1">
            <i class="far fa-edit"></i> 
            Update
          </p>
          <p 
            (click)="openConfDialog(user._id)" 
            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block btnStyleDanger font-xs m-0 p-1">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> 
            Delete
          </p>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

at the userlist.component.ts file,

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
    this.photoBaseUrl = '../../assets/images';    
  }
```

At the **Back-end** My image **upload Controllers File** :

```
controller.storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './angular-crud/src/assets/images',
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
      cb(null, file.fieldname + req.params.id + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
  });
```

**back-end image upload route :** 
//upload profile or avatar route

```
router.post('/uploadPic/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    controllers.upload(req, res, (err) => {
      if(err){
        res.json({
            success: false,
            msg: err
        });
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        if(req.file == undefined){
            res.json({
                success: false,
                msg: "Sorry! No File Selected."
            });
        }else{
          res.json({
            success: true,
            msg: "Great job! Image uploaded successfully."
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using `ng serve`, which runs a Webpack Dev Server. That builds the app and serves it from a virtual directory. It doesn't serve the actual `src/assets`, so if you copy a file to `src` while running, it doesn't update the virtual directory until you rebuild the app.

Since you need upload functionality, it's time to implement serving static files with your Express server instead:

```
const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(
    __dirname, '..', 'path', 'to', 'client-app', 'dist'
)));
```

Then, instead of ng serve, run `ng build --dev --watch` so it'll rebuild to dist when you change your Angular code.

**Edit:**
Note that you shouldn't use `dist` for uploaded files if you care about keeping those files. Each time ng cli rebuilds the app, the `dist` will be wiped. So use another upload directory instead, that's outside the `dist` folder created by ng cli. You can tell Express to serve files from there too, using another `express.static` call. Assets-directory should only be used for static assets that belong to, and you ship with your app.

Comment: when i'm giving the command, the process started but not completing the bundle making. i tried 3, 4 times.

Comment: no. it does not. just stopped and the cursor blinking.

Comment: You sure it didn't build and now it's waiting for changes? Is there a dist directory at that point?

Comment: No. It didn't build completely.

Comment: Update everything in your package.json and global @angular/cli, try again, if still doesn't work it's probably a topic for another question.